# iFrame in dijit.Dialog: Dojo V1.8 does not behave like Dojo V1.7

Tags: iframe, dojo

I have a dijit.dialog, containing an iFrame.
The iFrame is loaded with dijit widgets (inpitText, DateText, ...).
All is working fine in Dojo V1.7.
I try to migrated to Dojo V1.8 : now, when I try to focus in a widget in the iFrame, the focus is automatically moved to 1st item of the Dialog box.

Why is behaviour different from V1.7 to V1.8.
How to retrieve expected behavior (existing in V1.7) with the V1.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set autofocus=false when create the dialog.